# Unable to use Environment variables in Remix.js in localhost

Tags: typescript, strapi, loader, remix.run

I am using Remix.run with typescript to build a website but I am not being able to use Environment variables in my remix application. In my case i want to fetch a URL from a strapi server and include it in my component markup in SSR **without** using `useEffect` or `useState` any client side rendering methods. In order to do that i need to access the strapi base url from my .env file in build time. 
export async function loader() {
checkEnvVars(); // Check environmental variables

```
const response = await fetch(`${process.env.STRAPI_URL_BASE}${IMG_ENDPOINT}`, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${process.env.STRAPI_API_TOKEN}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}); 
checkStatus(response);
const data = await response.json();
if (data.error) {
    throw new Response("Error loading data from Strapi", { status: 500 });
}
const imageUrl = data.data[0].attributes.bgImage.data[0].attributes.url;
return json({ imageUrl }); };
```

and i am using it in my tsx component like this
`const imageUrl = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();`
[image: Error related to the Environment var because it can't find it in the client]
How can I access the strapi_base_url from .env file in build time?

Answer (score 0):

You can only access `process.env` on the server (e.g., your loaders and actions). To access these variables from the client/browser, you need to return them from your loader.

Here's the documentation describing how to do this. Essentially you return the values you need from your root loader, then create a `<script>` block to set the variables on the `window` object.

https://remix.run/docs/en/1.19.3/guides/envvars#browser-environment-variables